# amcl_pose vs odom/pose

Tags: gazebo, navigation, odometry, turtlebot, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What is the difference between amcl_pose and odom/pose? I am running the gazebo simulator and making the turtlebot go from one point to another. The task completes without any issues. However, the pose values in each of these topics do not match. They are sort of close, but are definitely not THAT close. Is it one the REAL position of the turtlebot and the other one where the actual robot thinks it is?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243532/amcl_pose-vs-odom/pose/) by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, `/odom/pose` is the **relative** pose, `/amcl/pose` is the **absolute** pose.

The odometry knows how far your robot has gone and how much the angle of rotation, and calculate the position and orientation for you. But odometry is only right for a short time because of slipping and accumulated error.

`amcl` uses a particle filter to track the pose of a robot against a known map. `amcl` gets the absolute or global pose of the robot and fix the tf `map->odom` to make the robot pose right. You can consider `amcl` as the **REAL** pose. And `amcl` is responsible to fix the error of odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2